# Change error message of links with spaces

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks

When you post a link using the `Insert Hyperlink` toolbar button, if the link has a space before the link, then it will say something along the lines of

> Link to `http://%20http://blahblahblah.html` are not allowed

[image]

The behavior does make sense. The smart box notices that the first few characters arent `http`, so it inserts this at the beginning of the link, and the `%20` is the code for a space

However, to a new user, this can be quite intimidating. They posted their link into a box that was supposed to render it in a specific way. And suddenly they are being told that they can't post that link.

This is an especially big problem, because it has been researched that the brain sees only one instance of a word if it is repeated. So the user only see one `http://`, so they see nothing wrong with their link.

So instead of continuing the series of heart attacks by seeing this message, lets change it.

One way to accomplish it would be to strip out the space at the beginning of the url if there is one. It could be accomplished using a simple regex expression. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7151225/1470950) could be what we are looking for. It uses this code to remove the spaces

```
return str.replace(/\s/g, '');
```